# How to separate a title from the year when the title continues into several columns separated by symbol " \ "

Tags: r

I have imdb.csv dataset and I want to separate a title from the year in different columns. The problem is, that there are cases when title ends with " \ " and in these cases the title continues into the next column. What could be the ways to separate year and the string that is before the year?

[image]

As you can see in some rows the title even continues to url column. What could be the best way to solve this?

Here is the code, where I tried to move every entry of the column to the previous column ( in case the title entry ends with " \ ").

```
for(i in 3:ncol(imdb)) {
                        if(str_detect(imdb$title, "\\\\$")) {
                         title <- substr(x = imdb$title, start = 1, 
                                         stop = nchar(as.character(imdb$title))-1)
                         title <- paste(title, imdb[i], sep = "")
                        }}
                        imdb$title <- title
                                for (i in 3:(ncol(imdb))-1) {
                                                        imdb[, i]  = imdb[, i+1]    
                                                              }
```

But the code issues a warning:

```
In if (str_detect(title, "\\\\$")) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does that mean that if can be used only for one string and not for column? I tried to wrap it into for cycle, but again some error occurred.

Comment: I'd suggest running some kind of regex script to capture all the cells with a \ at the end, then recombine them into a single object. That being said, you may check how you are importing the data (check encoding parameters, file format, etc.) Have you tried opening the file in excel or other spreadsheet program to see if it has the same problem?

Comment: @Doug I updated my post, where I try to solve the issue using for cycle. I managed to do it for one column, but I thought that there must be a more efficient way to conduct the procedure for all columns. I got a warning message, so I want to know where the issue is.

Comment: please do not post pictures of your data! Rather, a section of it using dput

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps, but it might be better to paste the full string together and then extract the year:

```
library(stringr)

test <-  c("aaa hh \\ hhf \\(1984)", "aaad \\(1234)")

str_extract(test, "(\\d{4})")
[1] "1984" "1234"
```

Similarly, you can delete the years in the original string using gsub.